# Automatic spark schema inference for custom data source

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.5

I'm implementing spark(1.5.2) sql RelationProvider for custom data source (properties files).

Can some one please explain how automatic inference algorithm should be implemented?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35372282/1560062

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to create a `StructType` that represents your schema. A `StructType` contains an `Array[StructField]`, where each element of the array corresponds to a column in your schema. A `StructField` can be any supported `DataType` -- including another `StructType` for nested schemas.

Creating a schema can be as simple as:

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("col1", StringType),
  StructField("col2", LongType)
))
```

If you want to generate a schema from a complex dataset -- one that includes nested `StructTypes` -- then you most likely need to create a recursive function. A good example of what such a function looks like can be found in the `spark-avro` integration library. The function **[toSqlType](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/avro/SchemaConverters.scala#L42)** takes an `Avro` schema and converts it into a Spark `StructType`.

Comment: Thanks @david-griffin, but I'm after **automatic schema discovery/inference**. How should should I sample the data and merge the schema ?